# Sublime Text 3: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, sublimetext

So I was doing things with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsG6dJlLBDw&t=640s and everything was grate til I pressed f7 in main.cpp and I got this response "fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory". I watched every step of the tutorial once again and corrected some mistakes but this error still comes up.
My code looks like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "bin/..",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-project"]
        }
    ],

    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Build Debug",
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "cmd": "g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++14 -g -Wall -m64 -I include -I C:/SDL2-w64/include && g++ *.o -o bin/debug/main -L C:/SDL2-w64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image && start bin/debug/main",
            "selector": "source.c++",
            "shell": true

        }
    ]
    
}
```

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h> 
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get()
    retrun 0;
}
```

I'm new to coding so sorry if it's totally easy but I'm trying to solve it for 2h and nothing helps.

Comment: What is the full path to `SDL2/SDL.h` ?  You need to add the parent directory of `SDL2/SDL.h` to the include path.

Comment: Can you descirbe it in more datail? I don't know what parent driectory is.